# Python - PyQt : Continue after a QThread is finished

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I have a for loop in a QThread, which is started from the main GUI via a push button. When the for loop is over I would like to come back to the main thread (which is inside the Gui class) and do something else.
As far as I understood, one should use the join method to wait for the thread to be finished. In my case it seems that MyThread is never finished.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as QtW
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

class MyWindow(QtW.QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle('MyWindow')
    self._main = QtW.QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self._main) 
    self.button = QtW.QPushButton('Do it', self)
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.MyMethod)
    self.layout = QtW.QGridLayout(self)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
    self.setLayout(self.layout)


  def MyMethod(self):
    self.n = 5
    self.loadthread = MyThread(self.n)
    self.loadthread.start()
    self.loadthread.join() # Will wait for the thread until it finishes its task
    print('thread finished')


class MyThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, n):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.n = n

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            print(i)
        print('cycle finished')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance() # checks if QApplication already exists 
    if app is None: # create QApplication if it doesnt exist 
        app = QtW.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainGui = MyWindow()
    mainGui.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    app.exec_()
```

The output of the cose is

```
0
1
2
3
4
cycle finished
```

and `print('thread finished')` is never reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QThread` does not have the `join()` method, so your application should quit unexpectedly and point to the following error message.

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MyWindow "", which already has a layout
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MyWindow "", which already has a layout
0
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in MyMethod
    self.loadthread.join() # Will wait for the thread until it finishes its task
AttributeError: 'MyThread' object has no attribute 'join'
4
cycle finished
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If you want to execute some task after it is finished executing the thread you must use the `finished` signal of `QThread`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('MyWindow')
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main) 
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Do it')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.my_method)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self._main)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def my_method(self):
        self.n = 5
        self.loadthread = MyThread(self.n, self)
        self.loadthread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self.loadthread.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        print('thread finished')


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, n, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.n = n

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            print(i)
        print('cycle finished')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None: 
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainGui = MyWindow()
    mainGui.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks! This was instructive!